# How to play 3gp Video on JWPlayer

Tags: asp.net, fancybox, jwplayer

We are Using JW Player version (6) on our website.

Unable to play 3gp Video on JWPlayer with the fancy box on website, can you please suggest the possible solution.

OR

May recommend any other player that will play (3gp, mp4 & mov) file using the fancybox on website.